# Not getting refresh token in react-google-login

Tags: authorization, refresh-token

I am using **react-google-login** to authorise accounts and I am getting the access_token and other details but not the refresh token, even getting the authorisation code, I am unable to get the refresh token. Can anybody help ?

Here is how I am doing it

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId="MY_CLIENT_ID"
  buttonText="Login"
  cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
  onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
  scope={'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'}
/>
```

Thanks in advance.